# Close Mutant Handle

Tags: c++

I am using a program called Process Hacker, and from that program I am able to cancel handles from programs, here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

I want to cancel the selected Mutant Handle using C++. Sadly I don't have any code to show since I have not a single clue of what to even Google for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A "mutant" is a mutex... terminating a process mutex abnormally is generally poor practice and will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: A `mutant` is a mutex I believe.

Comment: Yes, I understand the consequences of closing them that may occur, I have been using this program to do it manually a lot before, but now I want to make one on my own

Comment: You may want to simply review what ProcessHacker is doing: http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Closing a handle on a thread doesn't terminate the thread. The documentations don't say this. Consider the same to be true for a handle to a process, obviously.
Until all the handles to the object are freed with `CloseHandle`, actually your operative system won't destroy the kernel object.

You can also call `ReleaseMutex()`, which is a simple delegate to `CloseHandle()` function.